# Screen readers reading error message after reading next elements label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, accessibility

When am skipping input fields am showing a error message under the input field. Also to read the error message by screen readers am using `role="alert"` and also tried using `aria-live="assertive"` (without role). In both the case screen readers are reading the error message but not immediate. It reads the element label first and then the error message of previous element.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vivekvikranth/pen/oVBwZv)

Code Snippet

```
<form>
  <section>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="fname" class="eleField" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" required aria-label="First name"/>
    <div class="inline-message" role="alert">
      Enter fname
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="lname" 
             class="eleField" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" required aria-label="Last name"/>
      <div class="inline-message" role="alert">
        Enter Lname
    </div>
  </section>
</form>

$(document).on('blur', '.eleField', function() {
   if ($(this).val() === '') {
     $(this).attr('aria-invalid', true);
     $(this).next('.inline-message').show();
   } else {
     $(this).attr('aria-invalid', false);
     $(this).next('.inline-message').hide();
   }                
 });
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `<label>` for your inputs? In terms of accessibility its a best practice to use a label element for each input which most screen readers will handle appropriately. The aria-label attribute should only be used in circumstances where there is no native labeling for the given element.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using HTML5 Validation instead of using custom JavaScript.  Because they are native to the browser, the support with assistive technologies is a bit better.

However, if you do want display custom alerts, you don't need to add role=alert or aria-live attributes.  "aria-live" is just a suggestion to the screen reader, and it is sometimes ignored.  A better practice is to:

**Associate the error message to the input box**

Add a unique ID to the error message container. Then add the aria-describedby attribute to the input element, with a value of the error message's ID.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="fname" class="eleField" aria-describedby="fname-error"/>
     <div id="fname-error" class="inline-message">
      Enter fname
    </div>
```

**Focus the first input element with an error message on submit.**

You've already marked the invalid fields with "aria-invalid=true".  The below jQuery focuses the first element with that attribute.  When the field receives focus, it will also read the error message because of the aria-describedby.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   $("form *[aria-invalid=true]").first().focus();
})
```

Don't forget to also add labels elements for all your inputs fields. :)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/camtin/pen/drvjjb

Comment: Thanks @nicklundy I came to know that, When inserting a new error message
There is no need to do anything with focus after you have inserted an error message. When you insert it as the user tabs to the next field, they will likely have focused the next field. Intercepting TAB to steal their focus and bring it back to the error message would result in an unexpected experience for the user. It would consider this an anti-pattern. [link](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2017-04-04-how-to-make-inline-error-messages-accessible)

Comment: `"aria-live" is just a suggestion to the screen reader, and it is sometimes ignored`.  No, it's not a "suggestion" and if it's ignored there's a bug in the browser or the screen reader.  `aria-live` tells a screen read to announce the contents of the element if it changes.  There is no "optional" to it.  You really need to use **both** `aria-live` and `aria-describedby`.  `aria-live` will allow the error to be announced as soon as it happens.  `aria-describedby` allows the user to navigate away from the field and when they navigate back, they hear the error associated with the field.